# Domain pointing to IP address (Centos), where is running application

Tags: dns, centos

to be honest, Im not experienced in networking and I need your help. What's the problem?

I have a domain, which should pointing to IP Address, where is the application (orangescrum) running. This was set by our IT Department.

Firstly, Im a little bit confused, because **when I ping this domain, I expect to get the IP address of my centos machine, but the IP Address is different.** (centos machine has a private IP, I receive another public IP address).

Thats the first issue, which I dont understand.

The second problem is, that **when I open the domain in browser, I get the application, but without some images, javascripts, which should be included in application folder. I think, that the database doesnt work as well** (I cant log in to the application).

Application worked very well on my localhost, but as I pointing the domain to this ip address, there are a lot of think, which are not working.

I know, that I didnt explain the issue very well, so feel free, if you need to specify anything about the set up.

Thank you so much in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to route your machine if you want to access as public static IP or Private add to your DHCP web router if you got admin access http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.254 debian of ISP try too.

```
sudo ifconfig
```

In a intranet context you can add to your hosts the ip_lan domain.lan.com

```
on linux : sudo nano /etc/hosts
on windows : cmd as admin
         notepad c:\\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

the first may be solve the second problem, if no, just look on the code source looking for your "localhost" domain writed on the code source to changing/adding as a variable global and only one reference domain, simple for editing in the future.